# How to replace part of string via regex with saving part of pattern?

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have strings like this:

```
string s = "chapter1 in chapters"
```

How can I replace it with regex to this:

```
s = "chapter 1 in chapters"
```

**e.g.** I need only to insert whitespace between "chapter" and it's number if it exists. `re.sub(r'chapter\d+', r'chapter \d+ , s)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups, Something like this -

```
>>> s = "chapter1 in chapters"
>>> re.sub(r'chapter(\d+)',r'chapter \1',s)
'chapter 1 in chapters'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookarounds:

```
>>> s = "chapter1 in chapters"
>>> print re.sub(r"(?<=\bchapter)(?=\d)", ' ', s)
chapter 1 in chapters
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<=\bchapter)  # asserts a position where preceding text is chapter
(?=d)           # asserts a position where next char is a digit
```